# Custom category in liferay portlet

Tags: maven, properties, configuration, liferay, portlet

I'm really struggling with this and I can't seem to get it right.

I have a Liferay portlet that I have been trying to place in a custom category but it keeps putting it in the 'Undefined' category. I've setup my liferay-display.xml with a hard coding to test but it still doesn't do it. Note I am using maven instead of ant for build and dependencies. The portlet works fine it is just not in the category I want. Once built the liferay-display.xml is in the WEB-INF folder (which I believe is where it is meant to be). Below is an example of the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE display PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Display 6.1.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-display_6_1_0.dtd">

<display>
    <category name="Hello">
        <portlet id="Hello Portlet"></portlet>
    </category>
</display>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I've missed anything information wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portlet id must be the id that you give in portlet.xml - I'm not sure you can give anything with a space in it, but the following portlet.xml and liferay-display.xml would match:

portlet.xml

```
<portlet-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/p...." version="2.0">
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>helloPortlet</portlet-name>
        <display-name>Hello Portlet</display-name>
    ...
```

and liferay-display.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE display PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Display 6.1.0//EN" "http://www...">

<display>
    <category name="Hello">
        <portlet id="helloPortlet"></portlet>
    </category>
</display>
```

e.g. use the `portlet-name` element from portlet.xml in your liferay-display.xml as portlet id.

Comment: You sir are correct. portlet-name did not match. Next time I need to RTFM. Thanks.